# How to use linq to process and conditionally read text file into a List<class> or a dictionary

Tags: linq, text, process

How to use Linq to process the following scenario: here is the sample test file

"

^name A

valueA

^name B

^name C

valueC

"

I hope linq can process it and read them into a List or a dictionary

public class NameValue
    {
        public string colname;
        public string colvalue;
    }

like this:

({"name_A","valueA"},{"name_B",""},{"name_C","valueC"})

Basically each name line starts with a ^ and followed by a value line, but not every name has a value attached to it in the text file. In the name line, replace any space with _.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which should do what you want to do:
https://ideone.com/ThplS6

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var input = @"^name A
      valueA
      ^name B
      ^name C
      valueC";
      var pattern = @"\^[^\^]*";

      var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
      var dict = matches.Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(s => s.Value.Split('\n')[0].Trim().Remove(0, 1), s => s.Value.Split('\n')[1].Trim());

      Console.WriteLine(dict.Aggregate(String.Empty, (s, s1) => s + s1.Key + ":" + s1.Value +"|"));
   }
}
```

It uses Regex and LINQ.